# How to alias a type (e.g. string, int...)

Tags: graphql

I know from the doc I can [alias a field](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases). But how could I alias a type?

E.g. how could I alias a int or string type? Will `type MyStringType = String` work?

## Motivation

I have a `signin` mutation that returns an auth token, and I would like to write something like:

```
type Mutation {
    signin(email: String!, password: String!): AuthToken
}
type AuthToken = String
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GraphQL does not support type aliases.

You can, however, implement a custom scalar with the same properties as an existing scalar but a different name. It's unclear from your question what language or libraries you're working with, but in GraphQL.js, you can just do something like:

```
const { GraphQLString, GraphQLScalarType } = require('graphql')
const AuthToken = new GraphQLScalarType({
  name: 'AuthToken',
  description: 'Your description here',
  serialize: GraphQLString.serialize,
  parseValue: GraphQLString.parseValue,
  parseLiteral: GraphQLString.parseLiteral,
})
```

Here's how to [add a custom scalar in Apollo Server](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/scalars/). Keep in mind that doing this may actually make things harder for clients, especially ones written in strongly typed languages. If you don't need custom serialization or parsing behavior, I would stick to the built-in scalars.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!